# Update multiple columns in a row no errors but table is not updated

Tags: php, mysqli

I have tried this code but it does not update my table, can someone tell me where i am going wrong?

```
<?php
$TeamNow = $teams->TeamID->CurrentValue;
$GK1  = $teams->Keeper1->CurrentValue;
$GK2  = $teams->Keeper2->CurrentValue;
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "soccer_team");
if (!$link) {
    printf("Connection to the database failed. Error: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
} else {
/* update rows */
mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE teams SET ('keeper1_price', 'Keeper2_Price') VALUES ($GK1,$GK2) WHERE TeamID = $TeamNow");
printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", mysqli_affected_rows($link));
/* close connection */
?> <script>  alert ( <?php echo 'Updated Team No:'; echo $TeamNow; ?>); </script>
<?php
mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: Have a look at the [syntax of the `UPDATE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is with your current SQL query which is wrong for a `UPDATE` query, it should have been:

```
UPDATE `teams` SET `keeper1_price` = '$GK1', `Keeper2_Price` = '$GK2' WHERE `TeamID` = '$TeamNow'
```

For columns and table name you should use back-tick only and in most cases it's not needed and for the fields if they are string its recommended to use the single quotes however since your using MySQLi you should highly use prepared statement to prevent against SQL injection, here is an example:

```
<?php
// Your database info
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'soccer_team';

$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if ($con->connect_error)
{
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Here we prepare your query and make sure it is alright
$sql = "UPDATE `teams` SET `keeper1_price` = ?, `Keeper2_Price` = ? WHERE `TeamID` = ?";
if (!$stmt = $con->prepare($sql))
{
    die('Query failed: (' . $con->errno . ') ' . $con->error);
}

// Here we define the field types with 'ddi' which means double, double, integer
// and also set the fields values
if (!$stmt->bind_param('ddi', $GK1, $GK2, $TeamNow))
{
    die('Binding parameters failed: (' . $stmt->errno . ') ' . $stmt->error);
}

// Now we finally execute the data to update it to the database
// and if it fails we will know
if (!$stmt->execute())
{
    die('Execute failed: (' . $stmt->errno . ') ' . $stmt->error);
}

printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
$con->close();
```

[You can read more about `bind_param` and it's parameters here.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#parameters)